# Interupt backend function and wait for frontend response

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket, system-design

I'm looking for a good solution to implement a handshake between a python backend server and a react frontend connected through a websocket.

The frontend allows the user to upload a file and then send it to the backend for processing. Now it might be possible that the processing encounters some issues and likes the user's confirmation to proceed or cancel - and that's where I'm stuck.

My current implementation has different "endpoints" in the backend which call then different function implementations and a queue which is continuously processed and content (messages) is sent to the frontend. But these are always complete actions, they either succeed or fail and the returned message is accordingly. I have no system in place to interupt a running task (e.g. file processing), send a request to the frontend and then wait for response before I continue the function.

Is there a design pattern or common approach for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

How long it takes to process? Maybe a good solution is set up a message broker like RabbitMQ and create a queue for this process. In the front-end you have to create a panel to see the state of the process, which is running in an async task, and if it has found some issues, let the user know and ask what to do.

Comment: If everything runs smooth the processing takes around 200ms. I'll take a look at RabbitMQ.